# Qemu qmp snaphot-drive

Tags: vps, kvm-virtualization, snapshot, qemu

what is the correct method to use qemu qmp snapshot-drive ?

Is there any other way to create snapshot of qcow2 based VPS without using virsh snapshot-create ? They seem to corrupt the filesystem on VPS.

Answer (score 0):

To get a *consistent* filesystem snapshot, you need all of the following:

1. The qemu-guest-agent must be installed and running in the guest.
2. Run `virsh domfsfreeze guestname` before taking the snapshot. This tells the qemu-guest-agent to stop all filesystem activity and bring it to a consistent state.
3. Take your snapshot.
4. Run `virsh domfsthaw guestname` after taking the snapshot. This tells the qemu-guest-agent to allow filesystem activity to resume. But the snapshot will remain as it was when frozen above.
5. Back up the snapshot.